# How to compile opencv gstreamer plugins for android?

Tags: android, opencv, plugins, gstreamer

i am trying to compile opencv gstreamer plugins from gst-plugins-bad for android. I followed the instructions on https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/building-from-source-using-cerbero.html?gi-language=c and built gstreamer with cerbero. I downloaded and compiled opencv v3.4.6 (i also tried with many other versions, but its always the same problem) for android and added the generated opencv.pc to pkg config path (and also opencv2 directory to the standard path .../arm64/include/gstreamer-1.0). To save some time i also modified makefile.am to compile only one plugin gstcvdilate.cpp:

```
plugin_LTLIBRARIES = libgstopencv.la

#CXXFLAGS += -xc++ -lstdc++ -shared-libgcc -fexceptions
CXXFLAGS += -frtti -fexceptions

# sources used to compile this plug-in
            
libgstopencv_la_SOURCES = gstcvdilate.cpp #gstopencv.cpp

libgstopencv_la_CXXFLAGS = \
    -I$(top_srcdir)/gst-libs \
    -I$(top_builddir)/gst-libs \
    $(GST_PLUGINS_BASE_CFLAGS) $(GST_BASE_CFLAGS) $(GST_CXXFLAGS) $(OPENCV_CFLAGS) \
    -DGST_HAAR_CASCADES_DIR=\"$(pkgdatadir)/@GST_API_VERSION@/opencv_haarcascades\"

# flags used to compile this facedetect
# add other _CFLAGS and _LIBS as needed
#
# override CV_INLINE: GLib will take care of defining 'inline' sufficiently and
# OpenCV's define isn't good enough to avoid 'unused' gcc warnings (at v2.1.0)
libgstopencv_la_CFLAGS = $(GST_PLUGINS_BASE_CFLAGS) $(GST_BASE_CFLAGS) \
    $(GST_CFLAGS) $(OPENCV_CFLAGS) \
    -DCV_INLINE="static inline" \
    -DCV_NO_BACKWARD_COMPATIBILITY

libgstopencv_la_LIBADD = \
    $(top_builddir)/gst-libs/gst/opencv/libgstopencv-$(GST_API_VERSION).la \
    $(GST_LIBS) $(GST_BASE_LIBS) $(OPENCV_LIBS) \
    $(GSTPB_BASE_LIBS) -lgstvideo-$(GST_API_VERSION) -lstdc++

libgstopencv_la_LDFLAGS = $(GST_PLUGIN_LDFLAGS)
libgstopencv_la_LIBTOOLFLAGS = --tag=disable-static

# headers we need but don't want installed
noinst_HEADERS = gstcvdilate.h gstcvdilateerode.h


opencv_haarcascadesdir = $(pkgdatadir)/$(GST_API_VERSION)/opencv_haarcascades
opencv_haarcascades_DATA = fist.xml palm.xml

EXTRA_DIST = $(opencv_haarcascades_DATA)
```

but when i try to compile this plugin with `make` it always gives this error (and many more linker errors if i try more plugins):
[image showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcSSm.png)

```
[cerbero-android-arm64] root@ubuntu-virtualbox:/usr/cerbero/gst-plugins-bad/ext/opencv# make
  CXX      libgstopencv_la-gstcvdilate.lo
  CXXLD    libgstopencv.la
clang++: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang++: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang++: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang++: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
.libs/libgstopencv_la-gstcvdilate.o: In function `gst_cv_dilate_get_type_once()':
/usr/cerbero/gst-plugins-bad/ext/opencv/gstcvdilate.cpp:68: undefined reference to `gst_cv_dilate_erode_get_type'
.libs/libgstopencv_la-gstcvdilate.o: In function `__clang_call_terminate':
gstcvdilate.cpp:(.text.__clang_call_terminate[__clang_call_terminate]+0x4): undefined reference to `__cxa_begin_catch'
gstcvdilate.cpp:(.text.__clang_call_terminate[__clang_call_terminate]+0x8): undefined reference to `std::terminate()'
.libs/libgstopencv_la-gstcvdilate.o:(.data.DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0[DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0]+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Makefile:905: libgstopencv.la] Error 1
```

Can anyone help me? I've been trying to compile opencv plugins for a month now but no luck. Thanks in advance.